# Paginate in KnpPager not work

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, knppaginator

I have a problem with my paginate. My route :

```
show_product_category:
path:     /{id}/{name}
defaults: { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:Category:showCategory}
requirements:
    id:  \d+
    _method:  GET
```

In my controller :

```
    $aProducts          = $repositoryProduct->getProductsOrderByDateDesc($id);
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $aProducts,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),
        3
    );
    return $this->render('ShopDesktopBundle:Category:category.html.twig',array(
        'pagination'        => $pagination
    ));
```

I view :

```
<div class="navigation">
     {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
</div>
```

It's calculate normal the count of products and in view I see : 1 2 3 >.
But when I tried to get the page 2 in url it's send : ?page=2 but the list of products not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed to configure the page parameter and process it in your controller:

use this route:

```
show_product_category:
    path:     /{id}/{name}/{page}
    defaults:
        _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:Category:showCategory
        page: 1
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
        page: \d+
    methods: [GET]
```

and in controller:

```
public function showCategoryAction($id, $name, $page)
{
    //your code.....
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $aProducts,
    $page,
    3
    );
    // your code...
}
```