# Symfony 3 - KNP paginator error - Route issue?

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, knpmenubundle, knppaginator

I added a pagination using KNP Paginator. It works well except for one page that render a page for specific ID. This page worked well before I added the pagination. the function was

```
public function orderDetailAction($id)
```

For the pagination, I added the Request.

```
 /**
  * Display order detail
  *
  *@Route("/order/{id}", name="requestitem_order")
  *@Method("GET")
  */
  public function orderDetailAction(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ECAInventoryBundle:RequestItem');
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('r')
      ->innerJoin('r.item','i')
      ->select('i.name')
      ->addSelect('r.quantity')
      ->addSelect('i.id')
      ->addSelect('r.date')
      ->addSelect('r.remark')
      ->where('i.id = :ID')->setParameter('ID', $id)
      ->orderBy('r.date', 'DESC')
      ->getQuery();

    $details = $query->getResult();

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $result = $paginator->paginate(
      $details,
      $request->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
      5/*limit per page*/
  );

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($details)
      ->add('id', TextType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px')))
      ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px')))
      ->add('quantity', TextType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px')))
      ->add('date', DateType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px')))
      ->add('remark', TextareaType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px', 'required' => false),'empty_data'  => null))
      ->getForm();

    return $this->render('requestitem/order_details.html.twig', array('details'=> $details, 'form' => $form->createView()));

  }
```

The Twig file is

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
{% set Name = '' %}
{% for detail in details %}
  {% set Name = detail.name %}
{% endfor %}

<h1>Detail</h1>
<h2>{{Name}}</h2>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th scope="row">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="row">Date</th>
          <th scope="row">Remark</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {% for detail in details %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ detail.quantity}}</td>
          <td>{{ detail.date|date('d M Y') }}</td>
          <td>{{ detail.remark}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
{# display navigation #}
<div class="navigation text-center">
  {{ knp_pagination_render(details) }}
</div>
<hr />
<a href="{{ path('requestitem_balance')}}" class="btn btn-default">Back to Balance</a>
{% endblock %}
```

I have the following error

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Twig\Extension\PaginationExtension::render()
>   must be an instance of
>   Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Pagination\SlidingPagination, array given,
>   called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\var\cache\dev\twig\60\60f10f12ae3f80d30f6ac9425ed3eadb7f6a850a4574537165108f4cd8dfd500.php
>   on line 107

The controller route is @Route("/order/{id}" and the paginator uses this kind of route ?page=2. I don't know if this is the problem.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Pass the query object to the paginate method instead of the details object. You don't need to execute rhe query in order to paginate the result : knp do it for you. Then pass the result to the view instead of the details object

Comment: Matteo, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: hi @Ziumin done. Previously i post a comment by mobile for share a rapid tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the route.I changed the route  and the function parameters to retrieve the id and page from the url. I make the following changes to make it work.

```
/**
  * Display order detail
  *
  *@Route("/order/{id}/{page}", name="requestitem_order", defaults={"page": 1})
  *@Method("GET")
  */
  public function orderDetailAction($id, $page)
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ECAInventoryBundle:RequestItem');
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('r')
      ->innerJoin('r.item','i')
      ->select('i.name')
      ->addSelect('r.quantity')
      ->addSelect('i.id')
      ->addSelect('r.date')
      ->addSelect('r.remark')
      ->where('i.id = :ID')->setParameter('ID', $id)
      ->orderBy('r.date', 'DESC')
      ->getQuery();

    $details = $query->getResult();

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
      $details,
      $page,
      5
    );
```

Instead of using get(page,1) in $pagination, I use $page.

The answer of [Paginate in KnpPager not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301112/paginate-in-knppager-not-work?rq=1) help me a lot.

Comment: a great article which help me too: https://samuelweber.at/article/pagination-in-your-symfony-projects-with-the-knppaginatorbundle

Answer (score 1):

You make some mistake:

1) You can pass the query object to the paginate method instead of the details object (You don't need to execute the query in order to paginate the result : knp do it for you)

2) You need to pass the result to the view instead of the details object.

So modify your controller as follow:

```
**
  * Display order detail
  *
  *@Route("/order/{id}", name="requestitem_order")
  *@Method("GET")
  */
  public function orderDetailAction(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ECAInventoryBundle:RequestItem');
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('r')
      ->innerJoin('r.item','i')
      ->select('i.name')
      ->addSelect('r.quantity')
      ->addSelect('i.id')
      ->addSelect('r.date')
      ->addSelect('r.remark')
      ->where('i.id = :ID')->setParameter('ID', $id)
      ->orderBy('r.date', 'DESC')
      ->getQuery();

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $result = $paginator->paginate(
      $query,  // (1) pass the query instead of the result (better performance)
      $request->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
      5/*limit per page*/
  );

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($details)
      ->add('id', TextType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px')))
      ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px')))
      ->add('quantity', TextType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px')))
      ->add('date', DateType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px')))
      ->add('remark', TextareaType::class, array('attr' =>array('class' =>'form-control', 'style' =>'margin-bottom:15px', 'required' => false),'empty_data'  => null))
      ->getForm();

    return $this->render('requestitem/order_details.html.twig', array(
    'details'=> $result,  // (2) pass the result of the pagination 
    'form' => $form->createView())
    );

  }
```

Hope this help

Comment: I changed. There is no error. The page is empty. So I added to the twig file `<div class="count">
  <strong>Total: {{ details.getTotalItemCount }} records</strong>
</div>` and the totoal number is 0. By the way I need `$details = $query->getResult();` to the form $form.

Comment: hi @Eskinder possible there aren't items for the selected id?

Comment: hi @Matteo when I remove the pagination code. It works well. There are items for the selected ID.

Comment: @Eskinder try paginate the result of the query (instead of the query) The paginator support both (is only an optimisation). See what happen

Comment: that is what I did previously. And I get the error.`$result = $paginator->paginate(
      $details,
      $request->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
      5/*limit per page*/
  );`